# How to use "postMessage API" to Get iframe Response headers

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I have an iframe that loads a URL (the URL not in my domain) and that URL after it loads inside the iframe gives 302 redirect. My question is that is it possible to get that 302 redirect URL value after the iframe  loads using JavaScript or postMessage API or anything else?
Note : the loaded Url is not mine (not in the same domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no.

The author of the page must insert the code necessary to use the Messaging API to "send" a message to the parent window.

So without the above, cross document and cross origin you cannot use the Messaging API.

Also, without CORS, you will not gain access to the iframe contents to scrape that data either.

Comment: Not that I know of because of the Same Origin Policy restrictions that sandbox the iframe. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access

Comment: OK , one more question and thank you in advance then i'll mark this answer
you mean their is no way to get error in javascript ??  @Randy Casburn

Comment: Yes. I just confirmed it again to ensure my answer is correct. You cannot access the frame without CORS.